# How to detect whether a particular cert has been installed on a Windows box?

Tags: windows, certificate

A pre-req for a particular application deployment is that we need a particular PKI certificate installed in the Windows Trusted Publishers cert store of the PCs before installing.

Is there any way to detect if a particular cert has already been installed? Ideally using  a one-liner command or a short script (that could be used for pre-req detection, or as a dependency check in SCCM 2012)?

There seem to be lots of commands and scripts out there for listing all installed certs, or all installed certs expiring soon, but nothing that I can see for identifying if one particular cert is installed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is possible with a PowerShell one-liner, you just need an easy way to identify that cert (I'm using the cert's ThumbPrint).

If you already have a known machine that you know definitely has the cert installed (easiest way to check interactively is by just using `certmgr.msc`) then you can use that machine to find the cert's thumbprint.

The following PowerShell command will list all certs installed in the Trusted Publisher store in the local machine context:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher
```

Obviously the path above can be modified, to list other cert stores, or you can view (a long list of) all locally installed certs using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert: -Recurse
```

The first command should give you an output something like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher


    Directory:
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher


Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
83EDC96EC3D55125EFFC77BC815F9133E268D5EB  CN="User, Test", OU=Testing Resources...
4DFF713712084D43DE6879C689F9A143C4A793BF  CN=Server One Self-signed
```

Once you've found the Thumbprint of the cert that you're looking for, you can use that to filter the results like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq "83EDC96EC3D55125EFFC77BC815F9133E268D5EB"}
```

That should return the details of the cert if it's installed, and nothing if it's not. Amongst other uses, this Powershell one-liner can be used as a Custom Script Detection method in an SCCM 2012 Application.

(Resources used: [Use PowerShell to Find Certificates that are About to Expire](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/05/use-powershell-to-find-certificates-that-are-about-to-expire.aspx) | [PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Discover Certificate Thumbprints](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/27/powertip-use-powershell-to-discover-certificate-thumbprints.aspx) |  [Using the Where-Object Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx))

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer but how can i check if it's actually there or not? should i just assign it to a variable and check if it's not empty space? Is this reliable enough?

Comment: I tried $? but it always returns true even if certificate is not there